# sed - how to use substring as variable that will find by part of substring?

Tags: search, insert, replace, sed, substring

I need insert/replace substring that will find by part of substring. Anybody know how do that?

Input:

```
#include  "PARTblabla.h"
```

Output:

```
#include  "src/PARTblabla/PARTblabla.h"
```

Abstract:

```
echo '#include  "PARTblabla.h"' | sed "s/\#include.*\"PART/\#include \"src\/PARTblalbal<!.h>/"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me which part of the string you have fixed. Assuming PART is fixed and blabla part can vary:

```
sed 's!^\(#include *\)"PART\([^"]*\).h"!\1"src/PART\2/PART\2.h"!' input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|(#include.*")(PART)|\1src/\2|' file
```

or

```
sed -e 's|\(#include.*"\)\(PART\)|\1src/\2|' file
```